# Bootstrap collapse on a < li > opens but won't close

Tags: javascript, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

So, I am developing a vb.net website and I am using 'collapse' to toggle some parts of the page. I'm trying to use a < a > link inside a < li > list item to toggle (through href) another < li > list item. I have multiple list items like that inside the < ul > but I only left 2 to simplify the code.

Now, my problem is that the toggle and collapse work fine until I click on another link. Then if I go back to the first one, it will open but when I try to click the link to collapse it, it closes it but then re-opens it.

Bootstrap.css version = 3.3.6 
Bootstrap.js version = 4.1.3 
Here's a part of the code:

```
<ul class="ModuleTabButton"  id="<%= ClientID & "_TabBtn"%>">
            <li class="col-md-2 col-xs-0"></li>
            <li a data-toggle="collapse"  href="#Tool_Info <span>Info</span></a></li>
            <li id="Tool_Info">
                <script>
                    function <%= ClientID%>_TInfo() {
                        ABWeb.GestionWS.LoadMagInfo('',function(arg){ $('#<%= InfoDIV.ClientID%>').html(arg)},ShowError);}                         
                </script>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-2 col-xs-0"></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="collapse"href="#Tool_Photos"><span>Banners</span></a></li>
            <li id="Tool_Photos">
                <AP:BAN ID="MagBan" runat="server" />
                <script>
                    function <%= ClientID%>_TPhotos() {
                        GestionRefreshMagBan('<%= MagBan.ClientID%>', '');
                    } 
                </script>
            </li>  
        </ul>
```

I really hope this is clear enough so you can understand -___-
Basically I you click on Info, the show and hide work fine. Then if you click on Banners it will still work fine for Banners but if you go back and click on Info, it will show but won't hide once you re-click it (it will try but somehow it re-opens halfway).

Here is my bundleconfig file

```
Public Class BundleConfig
' For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?  LinkID=303951
Public Shared Sub RegisterBundles(ByVal bundles As BundleCollection)
    Dim JQVer As String = "3.3.1"
    ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", New ScriptResourceDefinition() With {
     .Path = "~/Scripts/jquery-" + JQVer + ".min.js",
     .DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery-" + JQVer + ".js",
     .LoadSuccessExpression = "window.jQuery"})

    Dim JQUIVer As String = "1.12.1"
       ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery.ui.combined", New ScriptResourceDefinition() With {
     .Path = "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-" + JQUIVer + ".min.js",
     .DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-" + JQUIVer + ".js"})

    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/WebFormsJs").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js",
                    "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js",
                    "~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js",
                    "~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js",
                    "~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js",
                    "~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js",
                    "~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js",
                    "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js"))

    ' Order is very important for these files to work, they have explicit dependencies
    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MsAjaxJs").Include(
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxApplicationServices.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxTimer.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js"))
    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MsAjaxJs").Include(
            "~/Mag/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js",
               "~/Mag/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxApplicationServices.js",
            "~/Mag/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxTimer.js",
            "~/Mag/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js"))


    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"))
    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/Mag/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"))


    ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("ckeditor", New     ScriptResourceDefinition() With {
            .Path = "~/Scripts/ckeditor.js",
            .DebugPath = "~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"})
    ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("respond", New ScriptResourceDefinition() With {
            .Path = "~/Scripts/respond.min.js",
            .DebugPath = "~/Scripts/respond.js"})

    ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jQuery.FileUpload", New ScriptResourceDefinition() With {
            .Path = "~/Scripts/jQuery.FileUpload/jquery.fileupload.js",
            .DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jQuery.FileUpload/jquery.fileupload.js"})

End Sub
End Class
```

And heres a part of my Site.Master :

```
<head>
<%--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/api/Public/SiteCSS APPVER=1&TESTVER=1" />--%>
<%--<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />--%>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Slick/slick.css?ver=1.01" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Slick/slick-theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Themes/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Themes/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/DynamicView.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Site.css?ver=1.2" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/all.min.css?ver=5.5" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/font-awesome-animation.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Scripts/cropper/cropper.min.css" />
<link href="~/Content/Images/ABWeb.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="MasterScript">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />       
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jQuery.FileUpload" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="ckeditor" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Slick/Slick.js?V1.8" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/cropper/cropper.min.js?V1.01" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.lazyload.min.js?V1.8.4" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Helper.js?V1.01" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/ABWeb.js?V1.07" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.myutil.js?V1.8" />
        </Scripts>
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference path="~/App_Dynamic/Master.asmx" />
            <asp:ServiceReference path="~/App_Dynamic/Public.asmx" />
        </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: your html is not valid? Then maybe look at these samples: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/
The data-target, role, aria-expanded etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: Stop using collapse !